# Как правильно добавить зависимость androidx.datastore:datastore:1.0.0 в свой проект?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

столкнулся с проблемой добавления DataStore в свой проект
В градле добавляю зависимость следующим образом
`implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore:1.0.0"`
Но после синхонизации проекта мне выдает следующее

> Failed to resolve: androidx.datastore:datastore:1.0.0 Add Google Maven
> repository and sync project Show in Project Structure dialog Show
> Details Affected Modules: app

Как я понял он просит добавить google репозиторий к себе в проект, но у меня он и так есть, подскажите может кто сталкивался

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigation_version"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Помогло включением впн и добавление зависимости вновь